# How do I convert natural/Planck units to SI?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, si-units, unit-conversion, absolute-units

I am looking at a paper which has set:

$\beta=1/kT=1$ where k is the Boltzman constant.

It uses natural planck units ie $m=\hbar=k=1$.

Does it make sense to extract a temperature $T$ and mass $m$ from $\beta$ in SI units? And if so how do I do so?

Comment: If you mean to convert such a $\beta$ to SI units, sure why not; but a mass?  I'm not sure what you mean.  A temperature says nothing about the amount of mass involved.

Comment: @CarlLei okay so how would I convert the $\beta$ and I mean there is a particle with mass defined as m=1, is it possible to convert this to kg somehow?

Comment: if you are able to measure the mass of that particle, I suppose yes.

Comment: @CarlLei But the paper just defines these values. ie m=1 and $\beta = 1/kT = 1$ is there any way to convert these to a value of temperature in kelvin or mass in kg?

Comment: As a temperature, T (and therefore $\beta$ as well) is usually a variable, so defining it to always be $1$ seems weird. Maybe link the paper for more background?

Comment: This really is an opinion-based question, which is generally considered off-topic. When I was an active researcher, I never really converted anything to SI (cgs or natural) because it was a second nature. But I also knew some people who had to convert it to another unit system to understand what they were looking at.

Comment: @BartW the paper is http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.479515 page 2377 is where it defines the natural units and I'm trying to reproduce Fig 4. It it a theoretical particle with no interaction with a heat bath of any sort

Comment: @KyleKanos I understand that the question of whether you should convert to SI is opinion, however I'm asking how to do it. The software I'm using to model my particle takes input in SI but the paper I'm looking at uses these natural units.

Comment: No, your question is "Does it make sense to extract a temperature and mass from $\beta$ ins SI units?" That does not ask "How do I convert from natural units to SI?" (which probably should be off-topic as homework since it's a mostly straight-forward application of dimensional analysis)

Comment: @KyleKanos Sorry, I was just not sure if it was possible so I asked that first, I have clarified the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got a rough understanding.

It should be noted that $\beta$ here is actually a concrete value that can be related to a temperature in numbers, but it is not on itself a unit for temperature; it has apparently different dimensions.

Being in natural units means that we have to take each number seriously; the equation $$ \frac{1}{kT} = 1 $$ actually means $$ \frac{\lambda}{kT} = \delta $$

That gives $ kT = \frac{\lambda}{\delta} $; let's just say $kT = \phi$.  This $\phi$ has the dimensions of energy, and should have a value of 1 in the units used by that paper.  From those constants, the easiet path would be $ kT = \hbar / t $, where $t$ is the fundamental time unit used.  Without knowing what that $m$ is I cannot proceed, but if we assume that is actually the Plank mass as defined by $$ m_P = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar c}{G}} $$ and, if you can find clues defining the speed of light $c = 1$, we can produce a time unit $$ t = \frac{\hbar}{m_P c^2} $$

Now everything have concrete values and you can compute a temperature $T$ in SI units.  I am not 100% sure about the dimensions of the original $\beta$, but my feeling is that $\lambda$ should be the dimensionless 1; consequently $\beta$ has the dimensions of energy inversed.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about why there isn't a value of m. In the paper (http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.479515) it is defined as just m=1. So you think that means m is equal to 1 planck mass?

Comment: Does this mean that $m=1$ is simply equivalent to $m=9.12*10^-31kg$

Comment: and should it be $kT = h/t$ rather than $\hbar$ otherwise the units of temp would be $K/rads$?

Comment: @Cameron that's as far as I can guess.  There is no guarantee that this guess is correct; but at the very least, it is self-consistent.